# How to create splash screen with fade in animation in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
 void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await Firebase.initializeApp();
 runApp(SplashScreen());
 }

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() => FadeIn();
 }

class FadeIn extends State<SplashScreen> {
Timer _timer;
FlutterLogoStyle _logoStyle = FlutterLogoStyle.markOnly;
 FadeIn() {
_timer = new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
  setState(() {
    _logoStyle = FlutterLogoStyle.horizontal;
   });
 });
 }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
        child: new FlutterLogo(
          size: 200.0,
          style: _logoStyle,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

[image]

Here i am trying to create an splash screen in flutter with fade in animation but the problem here is i am not getting how to do it with Image.asset() I want to do it same for this image

[image]

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for your case? I gave the same case like yours

Answer (score 2):

You can use an **animation controller** in combination with **FadeTransition()**. For example, this implements a simple splash screen with a fading logo from assets:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  //Your animation controller
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
    //Implement animation here
    _animation = Tween(
      begin: 1.0,
      end: 0.0,
    ).animate(_controller);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller.forward();
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, MyHomePage.id);
      },
      child: Container(
        color: config.primaryColor,
        child: Center(
            child: Hero(
              tag: "heroLogo",
              //FadeTransition makes your image Fade
              child: FadeTransition(
                //Use your animation here
                opacity: _animation,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  //Here you load you image
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets_image.png"),
                  radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
                ),
              ),
            )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

FadeTransition makes you image fading. I hope this helps you. By changing the values of **begin** and **end** of the controller, you can let your image fade in as well.

Answer (score -1):

Use AnimatedOpacity for this job

```
class LogoFade extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => LogoFadeState();
}

class LogoFadeState extends State<LogoFade> {
  double opacityLevel = 1.0;

  void _changeOpacity() {
    setState(() => opacityLevel = opacityLevel == 0 ? 1.0 : 0.0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        AnimatedOpacity(
          opacity: opacityLevel,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
          child: FlutterLogo(),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Fade Logo'),
          onPressed: _changeOpacity,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```